# C# Selenium - Finding Element On Continuously Growing Page

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, infinite-scroll

I am trying to find a better way to do this than using:

```
js.ExecuteScript("scroll(0, 1300)");
```

I have a page where the data can change making the page height change up or down in size. So when I go to click on an element today that is located at `1500px`, tomorrow it may be `800px` and the element will not be found and the test case fails.

So what have you guys used to locate elements on a page where the size changes?

Comment: Find the element by name instead of by location?

Comment: @paqogomez This is probably one of those *on scroll load* page and the element does not exist unless you scroll it down

Comment: Hey Saifur. You are correct. I have to scroll to it first and then it is not a problem. As mentioned it is just a pain because based on content, the location can change and the original scroll to point is no longer correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using the below which seems to be working nicely. Thanks for the help all.

```
           IWebElement bio = SeleniumDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("path"));
                Actions actions = new Actions(SeleniumDriver);
                actions.MoveToElement(bio);
                actions.Perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work but you can try getting the max height of your page using something like this:

```
Math.max($(document).height(), $(window).height())
```

Then you can scroll using js.ExecuteScript.

I'd still use findElement after that to initate the click.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to take @ratsstack's answer little further and make it little easier for you to implement.
I am not sure if there is a cleaner way to do this. But, at least something that should work. You can provide an **estimated** number of scroll you think is sufficient for the page to load fully. Notice you can provide more number than you think is correct. It does not really hurt or will not cause your script to fail.

```
public void ScrollPage(int counter)
{
    const string script =
        @"window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));";


    int count = 0;

    while (count != counter)
    {
       IJavaScriptExecutor js = _driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        js.ExecuteScript(script);

        Thread.Sleep(500);

        count++;
    }
}
```

Note: I am using `Thread.Sleep()` to give the page sometime to finish loading. However, it is never recommanded to use hardcoded use. I am not sure about the technolgies you are using so really cannot provide any wait mechanism to wait for the page load. You can use something and replace the `Thread.Sleep()`

Implementation

```
ScrollPage(8);
```