# Scrolling an ajax page completely using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, windows, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to scroll a page completely using this code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) Browser;
js.executeScript("javascript:window.onload=toBottom();"+
                                           "function toBottom(){" +"window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight," +"document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));" +"}");
js.executeScript("window.status = 'fail';");

//Attach the Ajax call back method
js.executeScript( "$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {" + "status = 'success';});");
js.executeScript("window.status = 'fail';");

//Attach the Ajax call back method
js.executeScript( "$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {" +"status = 'success';});");
```

This code works fine and scroll the page for the first attempt but when page is scrolled down, new data appears at the page and this code failed to scroll it again.
So what I need is that someone will help me to scroll the page till end until scrolling is completed.

Do I use any loop for this?

Help/Suggestions/Response will be appreciated!

Comment: example of the page?

Comment: You can consider twitter or linkedin home page for example, like when you scroll down more tweets appeared.

Comment: but there is no "end" on that pages

Comment: On Linkedin home page, when updates are finished it comes to an end and no more scrolling is possible.
But I just quoted these as an example.

Comment: please try an example

Comment: Lets just assume that there is an end on the above pages after 20 scrolls. I think it makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

I had a page with similar functionality and another question I answered previously. I am not familiar with any generic way to know if page does not have any other elements on load. In my case the page is designed to load 40/80(forgot the exact count) element in each scroll. Since, most of the cases I know an estimated number of scroll(since I am using a test company and I know how many element present for that in db) I can estimate the number of scroll and did the following to handle that page.

```
public void ScrollPage(int counter)
{
    const string script =
        @"window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));";


    int count = 0;

    while (count != counter)
    {
       IJavaScriptExecutor js = _driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
        js.ExecuteScript(script);

        Thread.Sleep(500);

        count++;
    }
}
```

See my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662524/c-sharp-selenium-finding-element-on-continuously-growing-page)

**Java equivalency code**

```
public void ScrollPage(int counter) throws InterruptedException {

        String script = "window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));";
        int count = 0;

        while (count != counter)
        {
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(script);

            Thread.sleep(500);
            count++;
        }
    }
```

> **Use**

```
ScrollPage(10);
```

in wherever the scroll is necessary

Comment: Hi Saifur,

I tried your java equivalency code but it's not working.

Comment: Can you provide more information what's not working? And what is the exception?

Comment: Hi Saifur,
It only doesn't scroll down the page. As far as exception is concerned there is no such exception.
I've tried scrollpage with it's method. It only scrolled down the page once.

Comment: @FurqanUdDin Can you share the code you are using exactly? And possibly a screenshot/screencast of the page?

Comment: Hi Saifur,

I can scrolled down the page manually many times like more than 10 times

Answer (score 0):

So, I would do something like that:

```
bool pageEnded = false;
while (!pageEnded) {
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) Browser;
    js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.offsetHeight);");
    pageEnded = (String)js.executeScript("return document.readyState;") ? true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: it's not completely scrolling or what? Please tell me how and what are you doing? It could also be that you page is using some js framework and doing something unexpected.

Comment: Page only scrolled down once and then it stops again.
I am only using JavascriptExecutor for this. It shows error here:
bool pageEnded = false; (against bool it shows error)
Also, error on this line as well:
 pageEnded = (String)js.executeScript("return document.readyState;") ? true;  (error against true)

Answer (score 0):

The best Way to do this is the following (implemented in Python):

```
import time

def loadFullPage(Timeout):
    reachedbottom = None
    while not reachedbottom:
        #scroll one pane down
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,Math.max(document.documentElement.scrollHeight,document.body.scrollHeight,document.documentElement.clientHeight));");
        time.sleep(Timeout)
        #check if the bottom is reached
        a = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollTop;")
        b = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight;")
        relativeHeight = a / b
        if(relativeHeight==1):
            reachedbottom = True
```

You have to find a efficient Timeout for your internet connection. A timeout of 3 seconds worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

This scrolls down the page until the DOM doesn't change anymore (we are in the case of the bottom of the page being AJAX lazy-loaded, code in Python):

```
def scrollDown(driver, value):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,"+str(value)+")")

# Scroll down the page
def scrollDownAllTheWay(driver, max_scrolls=20):
    old_page = driver.page_source
    for i in range(0,max_scrolls):
        logging.debug("Scrolling loop")
        for i in range(2):
            scrollDown(driver, 500)
            time.sleep(2)
        new_page = driver.page_source
        if new_page != old_page:
            old_page = new_page
        else:
            break
    return True
```