# Clicking on element fails if page is scrolled down/up and element is outside current view

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I want to click on specific element, but this element is not displayed in current view, clicking on that element fails.

I tried to set focus on needed element before clicking using the following code

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.MoveToElement(element);
actions.Perform();
```

But it fails. Can anyone please help?

Comment: What does "it fails" mean? Can you share the error message please?

Comment: it fails on locating that element. As for error message "unable to locate element " as we are using custom error handling.

Comment: Might try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662524/c-sharp-selenium-finding-element-on-continuously-growing-page

Comment: This is literally what i am using and not working with me.

Comment: no one here knows your automation framework, so until you put the exact web-driver exception being thrown with the Firefox version and Selenium Version, people won't be able to to help you much.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things. Is this on a popup by chance? If so you need to switch to the iframe.

```
    public static void switchToIframe(string name)
    {
        _webDriver.SwitchTo().Frame(name);
    }
```

If the element is off the page and it is a scrolling issue you can try this:

You can pass in a value of 100 to move down 100px.

```
        public static void ScrollDownByAmount(string value)
    {
        var windowScroll = string.Format("window.scrollBy(0,{0})", value);
        IJavaScriptExecutor javascript = (IJavaScriptExecutor)_webDriver;
        javascript.ExecuteScript(windowScroll , "");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
```

Comment: this will work for sure. in my case the 2nd option will work as the link is not in a frame, but i dont know how many times i should scroll up/down to reach the needed element. also, i dont konw if i have to scroll up or down.
i need to make it more generic so that i used to use move to element, but i need to know why it does not work in my case?

Comment: I have had the same issue and could never find a fix. I would just scroll down 500px or so and it usually worked. The problem is if the page just continues to grow. What you could do is put it in a loop and say if the element is not found, scroll again and then just break out of the loop if it is found.